# Text field value not showing up in my view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm writing an application that receives OSC messages. Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBcCy.png).

When I put the highlighted code in receivedOSCMessage method (which is called each time a message is received), the text field does not show the updated value of my_textfield.text, even though it does print the correct value in console. However, if I put it in ViewDidLoad, it works just fine. What might be causing that?

Edit: receivedOSCMessage is a delegate method.

Here are the contents of OSCMViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OSCMViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *my_textfield;

@end
```

Edit2: text field created in nib.

Messages are sent manually through a separate app.

Comment: Can you please paste the code of OSCMViewController.h? It will help to understand how my_textfield and if this control is connected to OSCMViewController via an IBOutlet.

Comment: Where do you call `receivedOSCMessage:` or is this a delegate method? Please elaborate your question with helpful information/code ;)

Comment: did u hook up the textfiled from nib or do u create it in code?

Comment: Are you sure the outlet is connected to File's Owner in IB?

Comment: [Yes, it is](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19262670/Screenshots/03.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the method is firing, and that the content of the message has a float that is successfully being represented as a string.  You've also indicated that you can see the content of the text field when setting it's value in `viewDidLoad`.

That's strong evidence that the receivedMessage method is firing *before* the view is ready.  To confirm, add a breakpoint in both `viewDidLoad` and in `receivedMessage`.  My guess is that you'll see the `receivedMessage` breakpoint hit first.

The other possibility is that the message receiving component is sending the delegate message off the main thread, and your UI updates are being missed that way.  Try, in the receivedOSCMessage method to wrap your code in a main thread block like this...

```
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // do the ui work here
       my_textfield.text = dat_string;
    });
```

Comment: I just noticed in the viewDidLoad code that it looks like you're setting up the messaging there, which weakens my hypothesis.  Any chance that you're doing that earlier someplace else, too, like in the presentingViewController?

Comment: Just tried it, the breakpoint in viewDidLoad hit first. Also, I send messages manually through a separate app.